# Custom class for EEPROM Read / Write bytes

Tags: c++, arduino, avr

I cannot figure out how to read/write to eeprom using the following class:

```
#include <avr/eeprom.h>
#include "myclass.hpp"

uint16_t arraySize = 0;
struct param {
    char name[10];
    char value[20];
};
std::vector<param> arrayOfParams;
std::vector<param>::iterator iterator;

MyClass::Myclass() {
    read(0, &arraySize, sizeof(arraySize));
};

void MyClass::reset() {
    arraySize = 0;
    uint16_t addr = sizeof(arraySize);
    write(0, &arraySize, addr);
    uint8_t buffer[16];
    memset(buffer, 0xFF, sizeof(buffer));
    while(addr < 1024) {
        eeprom_write_block(buffer, (void*)addr, sizeof(buffer));
        addr += sizeof(buffer);
    }
};

void MyClass::read(uint16_t from, void * result, uint16_t size) {
    byte * b = (byte*)result;
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
         *b++ = eeprom_read_byte(from++);
    }
};

void MyClass::write(uint16_t from, void * data, uint16_t size) {
    const byte * b = (const byte*)data;
    for(uint16_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        eeprom_write_byte(from++, *b++);
    }
};
```

The objective is to store "control bytes" that contains the size of the main array of structs - arrayOfParams.
First of all the script writes into control bytes space what ever value but 0x00. 
Then refuses to write the main structure arrayOfParams.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: One major problem is e.g. `sizeof(data)` when `data` is a pointer. That will give you the size of ***the pointer itself***, not what it points to. When passing pointers to a function, always add an argument for the size of the data being pointed to.

Comment: `(void*)&result` looks wrong to me. result is already the pointer you want I think: you don't need to take a reference to it (which would now be a void**, probably pointing at the stack) and then cast that result to avoid whatever warnings it was giving you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks. Fixed. Anyways the value written "control byte" is wrong. Looks like once I run reset() it wipes all from 0x00 into 0xFF.. then it writes 0x27E in control byte space…

Comment: @Rup It doesn't only look wrong, it *is* wrong. And means that `b` is pointing all wrong and the function will not work and write/read where expected. Which is probably the reason for the problems of the OP.

Comment: Updated. It shows: 
READ:  0x290
Wrote bytes: 2
WROTE:  0x290

Comment: `byte * b = (byte*)&result;` is still wrong. You want `byte * b = (byte*)result;`. And sizeof(&result) is still the size of a pointer and won't work either: you'll need to pass the length of the data in as an extra argument, the same way you have to for eeprom_write_block.

Comment: Updated. @Rup thanks. Now it's just stops at constructor

Comment: Still not there, sorry. `uint16_t * size` - you don't need to pass size as a pointer unless you're planning to modify it in this function, which I don't think you are. So you could just use `uint16_t size` and `i < size`. If you do need to pass it as a pointer then you dereference it back to its value with a star, i.e. `i < *size` not `&size` which takes another reference to the value (on the stack).

Comment: right. fixed. this writes: 0x28C when expected 0x00

Comment: I can't see anything wrong now sorry. I suggest you add some debug trace to read(), e.g. make the loop in read() `byte a = eeprom_read_byte(from); printf("read %02x from %04x\n", a, from); *b++ = a; from++;` now to check the values you're getting back from the EEPROM, since I'd say you're storing them correctly at this point. (Assuming the system you're working with is little-endian that is, but that won't make a difference if the answer you're expecting is 0.)

Comment: @Rup, there is a problem:
even if arraySize = 0; since the beginning, in constructor it has value of 2. Setting this var explicitly to 0 inside of the constructor, it gives the following output: 
>> arraySize: 0
>> read 000000 from 000002  <- from constructor
>> result: 1148                        <- from read()
>> wrote 000003 to 000007    <- from reset() where it writes 0 into arraySize's bytes

I know there is a mistake with type definitions somewhere in read N write...
Thanks!